# Can anyone identify this two-pin power connector?

Tags: identification, power-connector

Can anyone identify this two-pin, notched, rectangular power connector, please?

It's about 5mm (3/16") along the long side, and is used for a 7.2V DC supply to charge an internal battery.  One of the kids pulled the wire instead of the plug!

[image: two-pin notched rectangular power connector]

Comment: One of the most important measurements you can make is the pin pitch (distance from center-to-center on the pins).

Comment: It might be a good idea to mention what the device is.

Comment: That looks proprietary to me.  Two round pins, body can be injection molded for pennies.  It may be common enough that you might be able to find a cord from another product to fit it but it will probably be more trouble than its worth.

Comment: molded for pennies (in quantity).